# Swift3 - how to check whether a variable exists in enum and cast its type

Tags: enums, swift3

Here's a simple `enum` of mixed-type cases:

```
enum Options {
    case width
    case height
    case gravity
}
```

Both `width` and `height` can only have a type of `Int` however the last one - `gravity` - can only hold a type of `String` for example "north" or "south-east".

How to check wether a given variable exists in that enum and also cast its value to a certain type?

Say I have an array:

```
let arr:Array = ["width", "12"]
```

I would like to check if `arr[0]` ("width") exists in my enum and if so convert the second element `arr[1]` ("12") to an appropriate type (`Int` in that case).

When I explicitly set enum's type to `String` like so:

```
enum Options:String
```

than I can perform my check:

```
if Options(rawValue: arr[0]) != nil
```

That's far from ideal because as mentioned earlier my enum should hold cases of mixed types.

Is there a way to associate an explicit type with a case inside my enum so when I know that `arr[0]` exists in enum I can cast `arr[1]` to that type?

Comment: It seems that you misunderstood the functionality of enums. Please read [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3): Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)

Comment: Hi Pono, I would think a Struct, or a Dictionary would work better for this. I'm sorry if I misunderstand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Charlesism you are perfectly right - still learning Swift. I went with Dictionary to solve my problem.